# Embedded youtube video z-index in IE 9 (It was working earlier)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9, z-index, youtube-iframe-api

I have embedded youtube video in my site using iframe tag. I also having some fixed navigation in my site. While scrolling the page on IE iframe youtube videos are overlapping the fixed navigation which is having more z-index.

I have tried the below method :

**Method 1:** Applied absolute position for both iframe and navigation and increased z-index for navigation.

**Method 2:** Used a parameter `wmode=opaque` along with the URL.

**Method 3:** Used a parameter `wmode=transparent` along with the URL.

**Method 4:** Used a parameter `wmode=transparent` along with the URL and added an attribute `wmode="Opaque"`.

After trying with all these four method , this is not working.

**Note:** It was working earlier(1year back) while using `wmode=opaque`, but now it's not.

**-> My Code:**

> > HTML

```
<div class="navbar"> Sticky Navigation</div>
<div class="iframe_1">
    <iframe width="492" height="277" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGZ7KRjcXzQ?wmode=opaque" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="iframe_2">
    <iframe width="492" height="277" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGZ7KRjcXzQ?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="iframe_3">
    <iframe width="492" height="277" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGZ7KRjcXzQ?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" wmode="Opaque" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<div class="iframe_4">
    <iframe width="492" height="277" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JGZ7KRjcXzQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>  
<div class="footer_nav">Navigation Footer</div>
```

> > CSS

```
.navbar{
    position:fixed; width:100%; height:50px; background:#EFEFEF; top:0; left:0; z-index:10; text-align:center; font-weight:bold; padding:10px 0;
}
.iframe_1, .iframe_2, .iframe_3, .iframe_4{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ccc;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.footer_nav{
    width: 100%; height: 200px;background: #000;
}
```

> > Sreenshot

[image]

**Demo URL with sample code :** [Click here](http://codepen.io/ran161/full/jqroJa/)